# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions using GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I get this error when I try to execute my first Selenium/python code.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'Geckodriver' executable may have wrong permissions.

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

if __name__ == '__main__':

    binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,
                               executable_path="C:\\Users\\mohammed.asif\\Geckodriver")


    driver=webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

Comment: If you're on a linux system, use ```which geckodriver``` to find the path where the geckodriver executable is. Then use ```ll /path/to/geckodriver``` to show the permissions. You should have execution rights. If you don't, use ```chmod +x /path/to/geckodriver``` to give execution rights to all users.

Comment: @con-- he is using windows, so I don't think suggested thing would work

Comment: can you try to put into some other driver other than `c`

Comment: @GaurangShah yes, I have tried keeping my Geckodriver in D drive. but still getting the same error.

Comment: showing binary is not firefox executable

Answer (score 7):

Path for driver is not set correctly, you need to set path till the .exe as shown below

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,
                               executable_path="C:\\Users\\mohammed.asif\\Geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks! but it leads me to the different kinda error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: Check once whether this sample program run on your pc?

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:/Software/BrowsersDriver/GeckoDriver/geckodriver.exe')//set your path accordingl,y
driver.get('https://google.com/'

Answer (score 5):

make your geckodriver executable:

`sudo chmod +x geckodriver`

Answer (score 2):

While working with *Selenium v3.6.0*, *geckodriver* and *Mozilla Firefox* through *Selenium-Python* clients, you need to download the **geckodriver.exe** from [the repository](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it anywhere with in your system and provide the reference of the **geckodriver.exe** through its absolute path while initializing the *webdriver*. Additionally if you are having multiple instances of *Mozilla Firefox* installed on your system, you can mention the absolute path of the intended firefox binary i.e. `firefox.exe` through **`Options()`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

if __name__ == '__main__':
    binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
    options = Options()
    options.binary = binary
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
    browser.get('http://google.com/')
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First as per @shohib your are path is wrong, it is correct

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,
                               executable_path="C:\\Users\\mohammed.asif\\Geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe")
```

For this error

> error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable
>   to find a matching set of capabilities

You need to make correct combination of Firefox and Selenium Jars

Either update the firefox and selenium jars, I would suggest to use

Firefox 50-52 and Selenium 3.4.1